# How to calculate RMSE, skewness, and kurtosis of raster image?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem

I'm doing a project to analyze the impact different interpolation techniques plays on DEM accuracy.

In order to do so, I need to calculate the RMSE, skewness, and kurtosis.

I have:

1. an original source DEM,
2. a DEM generated from 10 different interpolation techniques,
3. a DEM generated by the subtraction of above two DEMs.

How do I calculate the three parameters?

Comment: Something like [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4802/rmse-between-two-rasters-step-by-step).

Comment: To calculate skewness and kurtosis you need a distribution which, you will not have with two observations (when directly comparing two rasters). The rule of large numbers comes into play with the distribution of the entire raster, likely converging on normal. You may want to explore a fuzzy numerical, moving window correlation or intensity scale approach. Take a look at this document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojo2lvqavz7hyaz/literature_scan_report.pdf

Comment: Although a statistical summary of the difference between the interpolated values and the (presumed) correct values is a good start, obtaining realistic and useful information requires considerably more. In particular, accuracy will be a function of the topography and the distances from sampled elevations; if that is not accounted for, it will be difficult to justify drawing any general conclusions from this kind of analysis. @Jeffrey I do not understand your remarks. Effectively the OP is asking how to compute L^p distances between pairs of rasters; there is no technical difficulty with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a statistically sufficient number of survey data points you could use the elevation values in those points to calculate the RSME using the code below.  The survey data table would need to have some existing fields including the surveyed elevation, and the interpolated elevations (from the add surface information tool in the 3d analyst toolbox).

Here is the code written for 9.3.

```
try:

import arcgisscripting, exceptions, math, traceback, sys
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.OverWriteOutput = 1
gp.toolbox = "management"



TheFeatureClassOfPoints = "Z:\Data\Cadastral\cadastrepoints\Cadastrepoints.gdb\Points\LummiDeltaElevationSurveyControlPoints"
InterpolatedValueField = r"deltaz"
SurveyedValue = r"surveyz"
RMSEField = r"RMSEdelta"


SquaredValues = []


print "Start cursor"
rows = gp.SearchCursor(TheFeatureClassOfPoints)
row = rows.next()
while row:
    i = row.GetValue(InterpolatedValueField)
    s = row.GetValue(SurveyedValue)
    SquaredValues.append(pow((i - s), 2))
    row = rows.next()

del row, rows    

n = len(SquaredValues)

SumOfSquares = sum(SquaredValues)

x = SumOfSquares/n

rmse = str(pow(x, .5))
print "rmse =", rmse
print "Add field."

gp.AddField_management(TheFeatureClassOfPoints, RMSEField, "DOUBLE")
print "Calculating field."
gp.CalculateField(TheFeatureClassOfPoints, RMSEField, rmse, "VB")

del gp
print "Finished"
```

## Geoprocessing Errors will be caught here

except arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:
    print gp.GetMessages(2)
    raw_input("ArcGIS Error, press enter to continue")

## Other errors will get caught here

except Exception, ErrorDesc:
    print ErrorDesc.message
    import traceback, sys
    # get the traceback object
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]

```
# tbinfo contains the errors line number and the code   
tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]

print tbinfo        # provides where the error occurred
print sys.exc_type  # provides the type of error
print sys.exc_value # provides the error message
raw_input("Python Error, press enter to continue")
```

Comment: Thnk u for the help... I'll try it..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in [R](http://cran.r-project.org/). Here's a script that reads in your DEMs, calculates your stats, plots your results and then writes to csv (if you really want to plot in a spreadsheet). Remember to add your own file locations and you may need to tweak the RMSE, I didn't check that.

```r
install.packages("raster")
install.packages("e1071")
library(raster)
library(e1071)

# your original raster
org = raster("~/dir/dir/file.tif")
org = na.omit(getValues(org))

# your computed rasters
f = list.files("~/dir/dir", full.names = T, pattern = "tif")
# for naming results
n = list.files("~/dir/dir", pattern = "tif")
n = lapply(f, function(i){unlist(strsplit(i, "[.]"))[1]})
# read computed rasters
r = lapply(f, raster)
names(r) = n
# convert to a numeric vector
v = lapply(r, function(i){na.omit(getValues(i))})

# Calculate your values
kurt = sapply(v, kurtosis)
skew = sapply(v, skewness)
# RMSE
RMSE = sapply(v, function(i){
   sqrt(mean((i - org)^2, na.rm = TRUE))
})

# Wrap up your results
df = data.frame(DEM = names(v), kurt, skew, RMSE)

# Plot results
barplot(kurt)
# etc

# Write results
write.csv(df, "~/dir/dir/file.csv", rownames=F)
```

Answer (score 1):

I calculated the rmse by importing the excel sheet in matlab...thank you all,I'm still on the process by adapting new procedures.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how do you achieved it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [GRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/), providing your DEMs are integer (a restrictive limitation). You need the [r.statistics](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.statistics.html) tool and also [r.mapcalc](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.mapcalc.html) (for RMSE).